# Proportions in AnyLogic

Tags: simulation, anylogic, agent-based-modeling

I am working an agent-based epidemic model. I am looking to move a certain proportion of those who are infected into another statechart called 'Death'. What would be the best way to trigger this transition in AnyLogic?

Let's say 2% of those who were infected with the disease died. So if I had 1000 infected agents over a period of time, 200 of them died. This is different from a 'rate' in AnyLogic transitions as the 2% is not per day (but over a period of time). What other ways of doing this are there?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SEIR example in anylogic does exactly this.. You can find the example typing Epidemic and Clinic. In the patient agent there is a statechart that makes infected people survive with a certain probability. You can see it in the following image:
[image: statechart]

the function `randomTrue(0.98)` will make it for you using a branch as you can see in the example if you want 2% of the population to die.